# How to implement the bootstrap in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

So I posted a thread about this problem, but it got on hold. So I rephrased so it can be  it  a programming question. This is my code below. I am trying to find the stimulated confidence level of a sample using the bootstrap.

# Step One: Generating the data from lognormal distribution

```
MC <-1000; # Number of samples to simulate
xbar = c(1:MC);
mu = 1;
sigma= 1.5;
the_mean <- exp(mu+sigma^2/2);
n= 10;

for(i in 1:MC)
 {
mySample <- rlnorm(n=n meanlog=mu, sdlog=sigma);
xbar [i] <- the_mean(mySample);
 }
```

# Step Two: Compute 95% Bootstrap CI with B=1000

```
B = 1000
xbar_star = c(1:B)
for(b in 1:B)
{ 
 x_star = sample(n,n, replace=TRUE)
 xbar_star[b] = mean(x_star)
 }

quantile(xbar, p=c(0.025, 0.975))
```

---

If you implement this code you can see that the output is 975.025 when it should actually be 0. 90. 
I don't understand why my output is wrong.

---

We arent trying to find the Confidence Interval, but the stimulated Confidence Level. How does the actual coverage percentage (obtained through simulation) compare with the nominal confidence level (which is 95%)? This is my code when my samples were given in a practice problem...

---

```
library(boot)
x = c(0.22, 0.23, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.28, 0.29,
  0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39, 0.42, 0.42,
  0.43, 0.45, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5, 0.5, 0.51, 0.52,
  0.54, 0.56, 0.56, 0.57, 0.57, 0.6, 0.62, 0.63,
  0.67, 0.69, 0.72, 0.74, 0.76, 0.79, 0.81, 0.82,
  0.84, 0.89, 1.11, 1.13, 1.14, 1.14, 1.2, 1.33)

B = 10000
xbar = mean(x)
n = length(x)
xbar_star = c(1:B)
for(b in 1:B)
{
x_star = sample(x=x, size=n, replace=TRUE)
xbar_star[b] = mean(x_star)
}

# empirical percentile method

 quantile(xbar_star, p=c(0.025, 0.975))

> quantile(xbar_star, p=c(0.025, 0.975))
  2.5%     97.5% 
0.5221277 0.6797926
```

Comment: What kind of bootstrap do you want? A non-parametric one could be done with `sample(n, n, replace = TRUE)` or the **boot** package which comes with R.

Comment: So why are you sampling 1000 sets of data using `rlnorm()`? In a non-parametric one, you have 1 sample of data and you take B bootstrap samples from that one sample. Compute mean on each of those B bootstrap samples and then take appropriate quantiles to give you a percentile CI.

Comment: Please never include `rm(list = ls())` at the top of your code. It can cause people to unintentionally clear their sessions.

Comment: Did you *even* look at what `sample` gave you? You need to use those values to index the 1 draw from `rlnorm()` to select samples from the observed sample.

Comment: What do you think `the_mean(mySample)` is doing? According to your code, `the_mean()` isn't a function but you are using like one.

Comment: Re you "Answer", you seem to be conflating (non-parametric) bootstrap and simulation. If you want to simulate you could draw `sims <- matrix(rlnorm(n * MC, mu, sigma), nrow = MC, ncol = n)`. Then do with each row what you were trying to do with `the_mean`.